# unable to avoid duplicates in bash loop over array to form two vars

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

My goal is that in bazel command no path should repeat and they are repeating.  Secondly, not sure why in 2nd iteration a path is missing.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
loop_array_for_bazel_coverage_single_path_ata_time () {
    bazel_apps_str="src/common/udc/cli src/common/udc/go/client src/common/udc/go/client/mocks"
    bazel_apps_array=("$bazel_apps_str")
    #set prefix and postfix to each element in array
    for paths_index in "${!bazel_apps_array[@]}"
    do  
        bazel_first_param=${bazel_apps_array[$paths_index]}
        bazel_param_second_array=("${bazel_apps_array[@]}")
        unset 'bazel_param_second_array[$paths_index]'
        string_var=$( IFS=$'\n'; echo "${bazel_param_second_array[*]}" )
        new=( "$(find "$string_var" -type f -name 'BUILD.bazel' -printf '-//%h/...\n')" )
        printf "\nbazel coverage //%s/... %s" "$bazel_first_param" "${new[@]}"
    done
}
loop_array_for_bazel_coverage_single_path_ata_time
```

output: if we observe below each iteration has duplicate paths. ex: `-//src/common/udc/go/client/mocks/... -//src/common/udc/go/client/mocks/...`

```
./tt.sh

bazel coverage //src/common/udc/cli/... -//src/common/udc/go/client/... -//src/common/udc/go/client/mocks/... -//src/common/udc/go/client/mocks/...

bazel coverage //src/common/udc/go/client/... -//src/common/udc/cli/... -//src/common/udc/go/client/mocks/...

bazel coverage //src/common/udc/go/client/mocks/... -//src/common/udc/cli/... -//src/common/udc/go/client/... -//src/common/udc/go/client/mocks/...
```

Comment: (1) If you want to avoid duplicates, put content in the keys, not the values. (2) `array=( $(anything) )` is an antipattern; see [BashPitfalls #50.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_.2BICY.29_.29) (3) Avoid `echo`. If you want to print array elements with newlines between them, `printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"`. See the detailed explanation of why echo is unreliable at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113, which covers why `echo`'s behavior is subject to change based on runtime configuration _even when the active shell is 100% certain to be bash_.

Comment: None of that answers the question, because honestly the intent your code isn't obvious to me at a quick read; because I don't follow the logic behind why it's supposed to be correct, I'm not in a good place to compare actual behavior to intent.

Comment: (Similarly, it's a lot more correct to define `bazel_apps_array=( src/common/udc/cli src/common/udc/go/client src/common/udc/go/client/mocks )` and not have any `bazel_apps_str` at all; the way you're converting the latter to the former depends on IFS value and is thus runtime-configuration-dependent; there are also a lot of unquoted expansions with behavior that's similarly subject to change with IFS and/or names with globs).

Comment: Anyhow -- how about you run your script with `bash -x` / `set -x` tracing, compare the actual and expected behavior of each command, and ask a more focused question about the specific place where it first goes wrong? That way folks don't need to try to figure out your code's intent and can focus instead on its actual behavior.

Comment: (also, it's generally a bad idea to use `${array[@]}` when expanding into a substring of a larger string, because that breaks your string into multiple arguments, which are in this case passed to `echo` separately -- which will cause significant changes in behavior if you switch from echo to a different command; stick to `${array[*]}` in that context so your string stays a single string even when an array is expanded into it. You'll see this difference in behavior when you use `set -x` / `bash -x`).

Comment: i added intent of code. last echo will be removed and bazel will run once i figure out my vars are correctly placed in second param.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: thanks. done. now it has no warnings.

Comment: To remove duplicates in an array in bash, I would either use an associative array. Alternatively, I would convert this script to zsh, which has the ability builtin to maintain arrays without duplicates.

Comment: i will search google for zsh. any hint how meanwhile?

Comment: I still don't know what the technical problem you encountered is, so no, no hints beyond those already given. The advice to use `set -x` to trace execution and compare the trace with behavior you expected -- and then focus the question on where and how expected and actual behaviors differ _at the level of a specific command from that trace_ -- stands.

Comment: Well, one obvious problem is that as you've edited the code, `bazel_apps_array=("$bazel_apps_str")` has an array with _exactly one entry_ (because the quotes prevent word splitting), so it'll have _exactly one index_, index 0. The way to solve that I already gave you -- get rid of `bazel_apps_str` already and define the array directly.

Comment: By "intent of the code", by the way, I didn't mean the big-picture intent; I meant a detailed description sufficient that a reader can see how any given line helps you achieve that intent, and thus can identify mismatches between what the line was intended to do and what it actually does. As someone who knows bash, I can see what each line of your code _actually does_ when I read it, but I don't know what you _meant_ those lines to do when you were writing them, so I don't have enough information to point out when intended and actual behavior differ.

Comment: (0) `bazel_apps_array` has only 1 element. Is that intentional? (Most other problems are related to that.) (1) Always create variables in functions with `local`; it saves a lot of headache later on.